# OpenCV Get 360 degree rotaion from T shaped body

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, orientation

I am new to this forum and hope you will be patient with me.
I am about to write my own vision system that will track only one kind of feature (The pins), allways, and run into trouble when it came to the orientation of my detected bodies. 
I do get the orientation from the eigenvectors, but only in the range of +-90 degrees. See below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHx1h.jpg

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and visual studio 2012 if that helps.

I use the findContours function to get the X and Y. 
PCA analasys to get the orientation (theta).
I have tried other constellations (SIFT, SURF, template matching) but this approach seems to give the best results.

It is just a matter of a boolean operator really, I could flip the direction manually if I just get a signal to do so.

The binary image used for tracking is seen below, is there any way to extract the "hat" feature in the picture and use that as a signal?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y4XX.jpg

BR

Jonas

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: Of course! Just snippets or the whole thing? The base of the code is taken from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS_uQGOQIdg. The pca analasys comes from an example in OpenCV. Which part of the code is the interesting one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reference..
I solved it by Template matching, it´s cheating, I know.
The template is rotated (wrapped/afflined by its center) in the angle calculated by the PCA analysis, the match value is then stored in a temporary variable. I do another match with the same tamplate but rotated 180 degrees and compare the matching values.
For reference, the template picture has to be angle calibrated in relation to the camera rotation (I do it by a slider). It is a static value that only depends on the rotation of the template when it was created. In other words...
Wrapaffline_angle = Calibrated_angle + PCA angle.
A picture of the process is shown below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6RD8.jpg

The Calibration_angle aims to maximize the differance between the two matches.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to apply some kind of threshold before finding contours. Because the axis you have is the one with the greatest variance of the data points. I suggest applying canny with fine-tuned parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sithereal! I applied canny before the template matching, unfortenatley I am not able to post the picture of the result. The eigenvalues and thereby the result, remains unsolved... i will look into "greatest variance of data points". Any other suggestions on how to preceed?